# "Name that tune" type questions

Tags: discussion

Should we allow questions that ask for trivia or identification of something (chord, guitar, song, etcetera)? [This](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/name-this-tuning) question inspired me to ask. I think it could be reworded to be a much more valuable question but as-is it's kind of like playing chord pictionary. We fielded a couple of "What kind of guitar is this?" questions and those seemed to turn out okay (basically a google scavenger hunt), but something as simple as what the asker is looking for might not be of much worth to the community.

If this were reworded to be "How can I identify and name any alternative tuning" then I feel like it would be a deeper and more valuable.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I identify songs somewhere?](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/can-i-identify-songs-somewhere)

Answer (score 3):

I think that Chord identification for instance is really of a different kind than "Name that tune".

You write

> If this were reworded to be "How can I identify and name any alternative tuning" then I feel like it would be a deeper and more valuable.

I agree.

Comment: This is correct. Questions with no substance are generally frowned upon.