# Asking instrument info from a reference material

Tags: discussion, support

Are these following questions are going to be considered off-topic?

- Given a certain audio track, asking which instrument was used to make *that* part of music in the track?
- Given a certain video, asking what is the guitar/instrument, and what's its specification of it, being played in the video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far we've had some open and some closed, but personally I don't think they are useful questions.  I subscribe to the reasoning in ["Name that tune" type questions](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/name-that-tune-type-questions)

Comment: I was more biased toward asking for guitar information. Like in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIXFAUmPiik), what guitar he was playing...or similar to this. (I eventually found out what he was playing.)

Comment: I think asking what instrument is used in a recording could be a helpful question. Maybe not "what kind of guitar is this", but which instrument in an orchestral piece, or what tools could be used to produce the sound output. Questions concerning particularly the latter could be good tools for people expanding their sound repertoire (using pedals, distortion, and other things that I as a classical musician don't understand).

Comment: @ReinaAbolofia "How can I produce this sound?" should be on-topic, I believe we've had questions like it already. In general we always want to push people towards "how" questions so they can learn something longer-term -- similar to the reasoning at the end of [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).